# Unknown string format for datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My datetime format in dataframe is `5/23/2022  19:22:33`

```
                  col
1  5/23/2022 19:23:12   
2  5/23/2022 19:24:13   
3  5/23/2022 19:24:49   
4  5/23/2022 19:25:48
```

Still, I am getting an error:

> raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
> dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format **

```
Z16.iloc[:, 2] = pd.to_datetime(Z16.columns[2])
Z16.iloc[:, 12] = pd.to_datetime(Z16.columns[12], infer_datetime_format= True)
Tat_Time = Z16.iloc[:, 12]-Z16.iloc[:, 2]
Z16['Tat_Time'] = Tat_Time
```

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your issue. Are you sure you know what you're doing with all that indexing? This should be as simple as: `Z16['Tat_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(Z16['datecol1']) - pd.to_datetime(Z16['datecol2'])`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```py
Z16.iloc[:, 2] = pd.to_datetime(Z16.columns[2], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: I also used errors='coerce' but I got NAN in all rows at Z16.iloc[:, 2]

Comment: @Deva It means your rows in `Z16.iloc[:, 2]` is not datetime format.

Comment: Hi, I found that my series have mixed format like

Comment: 3484  5/24/2022         21:50:11                   5/24/2022 21:49   
3485  5/24/2022         21:51:02                   5/24/2022 21:50   
3487  5/24/2022         21:52:48                   5/24/2022 21:52   
3488  5/24/2022         21:52:57                   5/24/2022 21:53   
3490  5/24/2022         21:54:04                   5/24/2022 21:53   
3493          0  5/24/2022 21:55               5542ZP3RG37Y0CTO000   
3494  5/24/2022         21:56:06                   5/24/2022 21:55   
3496  5/24/2022         21:57:38                   5/24/2022 21:57

Comment: '   
3488  5/24/2022         21:52:57                   5/24/2022 21:53   
3490  5/24/2022         21:54:04                   5/24/2022 21:53   
3493          0  5/24/2022 21:55               5542ZP3RG37Y0CTO000   
3494  5/24/2022         21:56:06                   5/24/2022 21:55 '